# MIPs Store Integers array

Tags: arrays, random, mips, greatest-common-divisor

```
.data
spacestr:  .asciiz " "
pow:
.asciiz "Ingrese numero de Iteraciones = "
mcd:
.asciiz "MCD "
linea:
.asciiz "\n"
proba:
.asciiz "la probabilidad es: \n%"

.text
main:

li  $v0,4             
la  $a0,pow
syscall                #imprime mensaje en pow

li $v0,5
syscall                #Lee el entero ingresado por el usuario.
move $t5,$v0           #mueve el valor leído a t5

li $t6, 1
li $t8, 1
li $t9, 0
li $k0, 100

mainloop:
bgt $t6,$t5,Fin

li $v0, 30
syscall

move $t0, $a0

li $a0, 1
move $a1, $t0
li $v0, 40
syscall

li $a0, 1
li $a1, 1000
li $v0, 42
syscall                #Genera numero aleatorio (time feed)
move $a2, $a0          # Guarda el numero en a2

li $v0, 1
syscall                # imprime el entero.

move $s5, $a2          #guardo en s5 el primero numero generado (pregunta!)

li $v0, 4
la $a0,spacesrt
syscall                #imprime un espacio

li $a0, 1
li $a1, 1000
li $v0, 42
syscall                #genera segundo numero aleatorio.
move $a3, $a0          #mueve el numero generado a a3

li $v0, 1
syscall                #imprime el segundo entero generado.
move $s6, $a3          #guardo el valor en s6 (pregunta!)

# Euclides MCD (GCD)

slt $s0, $a2, $a3     #compara si a < b. Verdadero s0=1 sino s0=0
bne $s0,$zero, SwapNumbers  

SwapNumbers:
move $t2, $a2
move $a2, $a3
move $a3, $t2
loop:
beq $a3,$zero,EXIT

move $t4,$a3                # c = b
rem  $a3,$a2,$a3            # b = a % b 
move $$a2,$t4               # a = c
j loop
EXIT:

move $s7, $a2               #El valor del MCD
li $v0, 4
la $a0,spacestr
syscall

li $v0,4
la $a0,mcd
syscall

li $v0,4
la $a0,mcd                   #imprime la palabra en mcd
syscall

li $v0,1
la $a0,($s7)                 #luego muestra el valor calculado de MCD
syscall

li $v0,4
la $a0,linea
syscall                      # Cambio de linea (por orden en iteraciones)

addi $t6,$t6,1

bne $s7,st8, exit            #cuenta las veces que MCD = 1 (primos)
addi $t9,$t9,1
exit:
j mainloop

Fin:

mtc1 $st9, $f1
cvt.s.w $f1,$f1
mtc1 $t5, $f2
cvt.s.w $f2,$f2
mtc1 $k0,$f3
cvt.s.w $f3,$f3

div.s $f12,$f1,$f2
mul.s $f12,$f12,$f3     # (primos/iteraciones*100)

li $v0, 4
la $a0, proba
syscall

li $v0, 2
syscall                 # Imprime resultado en f12

li $v0,10
syscall                 #Finaliza programa.
```

Hi to everyone. This code basically does 3 things:

- Generate 2 randoms int
- calculate MCD
- Prob of prime

The number of iterations decided by user.

So, here is my problem: I stored the 2 numbers and the MCD in $s5,$s6,$s7 and i want to print that as a table using arrays. First, if i try to put the 1 number into an array, i got this an error (stored word not aligned on boundary):

.data

array:      .space 32

.text

sw $s6, array, ($k1)
addi $k1, $zero, 4)

And my other problem is: How do i define .space for array since the user decide the number of iterations?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You are getting alignment exceptions because in MIPS access to memory must be word-aligned for words, i.e. address must be a multiple of 4 for 32bit words, and multiples of 2 for 16bit words.

To align a buffer you should instruct the assembler to do so by issuing an `.align X` directive, where X is 2 to align at word boundaries, and 1 to align at half-word boundaries.

So in your example you should put

```
.align 2
```

before

```
array: .space 32
```

About your second question, I would reserve the space according to the maximum allowed iterations of your program. Alternatively you can put that buffer starting at an address where there are no other variables/buffers after it.

Comment: Thank you, Gusbro. The align directive seems to work. About the second answer that's the thing , as i said iterations are decided by user, could be 5 or 20 or 100 or 100000. No limit i belive...

Comment: Well, there is always a limit, may it be the range of your integers or the memory you have. You may set you array as the last location of your `.data` segment, i.e. no other variable is defined after your `array` label. Then you can consider all the remaining memory as your array space (until it "hits" your code segment)